# Switch off ReSharper 6 Syntax Highlighting for specific file types

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

ReSharper has the habit of applying C# Highlighting to XAML files, meaning that every Node gets a Class Highlighting and so on.

I'm looking for a way to fall back to my default ColorScheme, but only when editing certain types, XAML to be specific.

Comment: There's currently no way to do that on a language-specific level: display item *ReSharper Class Identifier* is shared between different languages.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do that on a language-specific level: display item *ReSharper Class Identifier* is shared between different languages